# angular load id into data of module

Tags: angular, routes

I want to do something like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
  path: '', data: { title: 'Case'},
  children: [   
    {
        path:'',
        component: CasesComponent
    },              
    { 
        path: ':id', 
        component: DetailComponent, 
        data: { title: 'Case' + id },
    }     
  ]    
}
```

];

data: { title: 'Case' + id }, > is wrong but this is what I want. How to get id into data?

Comment: Why would you want this? You can simply retrieve the data and the id from the ActivatedRoute and combine them where you need it.

Comment: A menu is using this data and use title from my module